# I am getting empty cookie in laravel 5

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, laravel-5

I am setting cookie in such request as the following:

```
$cookie1 = Cookie::make('payment_method_id', 1, 60);
$cookie2 = Cookie::make('payment_value', 2, 60);
```

and in another page I want to read that cookie as the following:

```
    $val1 = Cookie::get('payment_method_id');
    $val2 = Cookie::get('payment_value');
```

but I got the empty, what am I missing?

Answer (score 2):

You are only making a cookie but not attaching it with response so you should attach the cookie using something like this:

```
Response::withCookie(Cookie::make('payment_method_id', 1, 60));
```

Check the [documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/responses#attaching-cookies-to-responses) for more information.

Comment: how can I create response?

Answer (score 0):

I hope you are setting cookie as below

```
$response = new Illuminate\Http\Response('Hello World');
$response->withCookie(cookie('name', 'value', $minutes))
```

And in next `request` you can get it as below,

```
$value = Request::cookie('name');
```

you can also queue cookie as below, so it will be passed on with next response automatically,

```
Cookie::queue('name', 'value');
```

[Read More](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/requests#cookies)

Comment: the same issue the cookie is empty